# Is the notation $\mathbb{P}(X \cap Y) = \mathbb{P}(X,Y)$ common?

Tags: probability, notation, random-variables

For two random variables $X,Y$, is the notation $\mathbb{P}(X \cap Y) = \mathbb{P}(X,Y)$ common?

In a probability class last year we had always used $\mathbb{P}(X \cap Y)$. This year in a stochastic processes class we used $\mathbb{P}(X,Y)$. I can't seem to find this notation in any material however. The course's recommended texts do not use this either.

On a related note, what other notations are used for $\mathbb{P}(X \cap Y)$?

Comment: Just $XY$ is sometimes used to mean $X \cap Y$. I haven't usually seen a comma used except when $X$ and $Y$ are described in words, though.

Comment: Not uncommon, particular for conditional probability, as in $\Pr(W\mid X,Y)$.

Comment: I see this used a lot, especially in measure-theoretic texts. As Ian mentioned, some people use $XY$.

Comment: Different books use different conventions. For instance, I have one textbook that uses **f(X, Y)** for both discrete and continuous random variables, referring to it in both cases as a "density" (e.g. calling it a "discrete density function" instead of the more common "probability mass function" in the discrete case).

Comment: Thanks for the responses and context everyone!

Comment: @Clarinetist That context helps a lot and makes sense since measure theory goes hand in hand with this stochastic processes module.

Comment: Just curious about the meaning of this notation - e.g. when $X, Y$ are discrete random variables, then $p(x, y) = \Pr\{X = x, Y = y\}$ is the pmf. Then what is $\mathbb{P}(X \cap Y)$? Do you mean the random variable $p(X, Y)$ or other things (as $X, Y$ are not events/sets). The intersection $\cap$ is used in conditional part because actually those $X, Y$ are short form of sigma algebra in which the operator make sense.